# How to import PKCS#12 into Seahorse

Tags: linux, encryption, ubuntu, public-key-encryption, pkcs#12

I have a PKCS#12 file which I have successfully imported into Firefox. Now, I would like to import the same file into Linux in order to use public-Key cryptography with these keys. I have tried to import it using Seahorse, but it failed. Maybe PKCS#12 files are designed to be used only with browsers? I would like to know...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

PKCS#12 is a standard made by RSA for PKI (public key infrastructure). This consists of a tree of certificates and their accompanying keys. Your PKCS#12 contains a key and a a chain of certificates starting with the leaf (end entity) certificate, and intermediate certificates that lead up - but may not include - a certificate that is trusted by the other side.

PGP, which is used by Seahorse is a different way of handling public/private keys, based on a web of trust (google it). It is not directly compatible with PKI(X) which you have now. You could extract the key and generate a PGP key out of it, but you would have to reestablish trust anyway, so you might as well use a different key pair...